# Compiling C to Wasm in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, c, compilation, webassembly

I am working on a project were I need to compile C to Web Assembly. I am using PHP so preferably something that can work with that. In my project I am taking input from a string, (let's say $foo), then I want to compile it to Web Assembly so that I can display it in Javascript. I already have the displaying part down if I compile the C code externally, but is there any way to directly compile this string? My code for displaying the Wasm:

```
let x = 'main.wasm';

let instance = null;
let memoryStates = new WeakMap();

function syscall(instance, n, args) {
  switch (n) {
    default:
      // console.log("Syscall " + n + " NYI.");
      break;
    case /* brk */ 45: return 0;
    case /* writev */ 146:
      return instance.exports.writev_c(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
    case /* mmap2 */ 192:
      debugger;
      const memory = instance.exports.memory;
      let memoryState = memoryStates.get(instance);
      const requested = args[1];
      if (!memoryState) {
        memoryState = {
          object: memory,
          currentPosition: memory.buffer.byteLength,
        };
        memoryStates.set(instance, memoryState);
      }
      let cur = memoryState.currentPosition;
      if (cur + requested > memory.buffer.byteLength) {
        const need = Math.ceil((cur + requested - memory.buffer.byteLength) / 65536);
        memory.grow(need);
      }
      memoryState.currentPosition += requested;
      return cur;
  }
}

let s = "";
fetch(x).then(response =>
  response.arrayBuffer()
).then(bytes =>
  WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes, {
    env: {
      __syscall0: function __syscall0(n) { return syscall(instance, n, []); },
      __syscall1: function __syscall1(n, a) { return syscall(instance, n, [a]); },
      __syscall2: function __syscall2(n, a, b) { return syscall(instance, n, [a, b]); },
      __syscall3: function __syscall3(n, a, b, c) { return syscall(instance, n, [a, b, c]); },
      __syscall4: function __syscall4(n, a, b, c, d) { return syscall(instance, n, [a, b, c, d]); },
      __syscall5: function __syscall5(n, a, b, c, d, e) { return syscall(instance, n, [a, b, c, d, e]); },
      __syscall6: function __syscall6(n, a, b, c, d, e, f) { return syscall(instance, n, [a, b, c, d, e, f]); },
      putc_js: function (c) {
        c = String.fromCharCode(c);
        if (c == "\n") {
          document.write(s);
          s = "";
        } else {
          s += c;
        }
      }
    }
  })
).then(results => {
  instance = results.instance;
}).catch(console.error);
```

PHP Code:

```
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end){
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = stripos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = stripos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
$string = 'blah blah {start c}#include <iostream>{end c}';
$foo = get_string_between($string, '{start c}', '{end c}');
//Something to compile $foo to Wasm
```

Comment: I don't see a single line of PHP here. How does PHP factor in?

Comment: @tadman I am using PHP to store variables and to get the input I need to compile to Wasm.

Comment: If you're using PHP, show us how you're using it, or it just a detail that's not irrelevant.

Comment: Added some code.

Comment: So I'm guessing the real problem is in the PHP code and the first bit of code is just some kind of artifact of what you've been doing? Help us out here and try and focus on the immediate problem at hand, not whatever process lead you here. While I'm sure that was hard to figure out, it's just a distraction.

Comment: A) Are you sure PHP is the right tool for the job here? JavaScript has solutions for this (e.g. Node.js + NPM modules). B) Can you bridge from PHP to some JavaScript back-end to compile using system calls?

Comment: I am open to suggestions of other languages to use. My only restriction is that I don't have shell access.

Comment: That's a pretty huge restriction. Unless you can find a PHP library that does this, which is extremely doubtful, you're stuck using Node and it's various NPM dependencies to make it happen. WebAssembly is a JavaScript thing. PHP doesn't deal with it.

Comment: Is there any way to load npm dependecies without command line?

Comment: Not really. NPM is a command-line tool. It also requires Node.js to be installed. If you're stuck on some really limited shared hosting platform what you're aspiring to do here might not be possible, or at least not possible *easily*.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can't you use a C/C++ to WASM compiler, e.g. Emscripten, and call it from php via sys_call? Maybe call [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) with emcc, pass the C code as argument (maybe write to a file first) and then return the resulting package back to js.

Comment: @prohit That would be a great except I don’t have exec/shell access.

Comment: What about WASMI/Wasmer?